# Unable to create path for cronjob in codeignitor

Tags: php

I have used this for the cron path
/usr/local/bin/ea-php55 /home/username/public_html/index.php Cron cron_job_updation and worked in live server.
i have another test server with PHP version 7.4.for some test purpose I wrote a corn job but unable to run cron job
/usr/local/bin/ea-php74 /home/username/public_html/index.php Cron cron_job_updationthe same is not working in test server(no domain name only IP )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Haver you tried `/usr/bin/php`? On command line you can locate your executable file with `which`. So `which php` should give you the correct path.